# Using modulo to loop array ends up in current element being the same with the next one

Tags: c++

I have tried to create an algorithm that tells you if a point is inside a simple polygon.I do that by finding whether the point crossed an odd number of borders.If it crossed an even number of borders we are outside the polygon and if the point doesn't cross a border,it just walks on it then we don't consider it as a cross.

Syntax:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int d1(int xa, int ya, int xb, int yb, int xc, int yc) { // localization function
    int delta = 0;
    return delta = xa * yb + xb * yc + xc * ya - yb * xa - yc * xa - ya * xb;
}

int main() {
    // A[0] A[1]  A[2]  A[3]
    int x[4] = {0, 10, 10, 0};
    int y[4] = {0, 0, 10, 10};
    int xm = 15;
    int ym = 15;
    int xa, ya, xb, yb;
    int i, c = 0, n = sizeof(x) / sizeof(int);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << i << "\n";
        if(y[i] = y[(i + 1) % n]) {
            if((xm - x[i]) <= (x[(i + 1) % n] - xm) && (ym = y[i])) {
                cout << "M belongs {A[" << i << "],A[" << (i + 1) % n
                     << "]}\n"; // point is on the border
            }
        } else if(y[i] < y[(i + 1) % n]) {
            xa = x[i];
            xb = x[(i + 1) % n];
            ya = y[i];
            yb = y[(i + 1) % n];
            cout << xa << " " << xb << " " << ya << " " << yb << "  1\n";
        } else
            xa = x[(i + 1) % n];
        xb = x[i];
        ya = y[(i + 1) % n];
        yb = y[i];
        cout << xa << " " << xb << " " << ya << " " << yb << "  2\n";

        if(d1(xm, ym, xa, ya, xb, yb) == 0 && ya <= ym && ym <= yb) {
            cout << "M belongs [AB]\n"; // point is on the border
        }

        else if(d1(xm, ym, xa, ya, xb, yb) > 0 && ya <= ym && ym <= yb) {
            c++;
            cout << "c is" << c << "\n"; // point crossed the border
        }
    }
    if(c % 2)
        cout << "M interior\n";
    else
        cout << "M exterior\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever we get to the point n+1 (which is the size of the array) it is supposed loop it back to the first point of the polygon with '%'.In my case it works for the first point and for the second it considers the curent point the same with the next one so it never fulfills the conditions. 
For the point M(15,15) i get this result:

> 0
>   10 0 0 0 
>   1
>   10 10 10 10 
>   2
>   10 10 10 10 
>   3
>   0 0 0 0 
>   M interior

It works for the first element but it doesn't work for the rest.
Since M is outside the polygon it should return M exterior.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you have e.g. `int a; a = complex_expression; return a;` you can simply replace it with `return complex_expression;`.

Comment: More related to your problem, I can see why you would want `(i+1)%n`, to wrap over to index `0` if you're on index `3`, but plain `i%n`? In your loop that's just not needed.

Comment: You should probably also spend some time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: `&&(ym=y[i%n])`? Did you possibly mean `&&(ym==y[i%n])`?

Comment: And please indent your code properly, the indentation shown is misleading. Perhaps that's the problem, you believe some statements belong in one scope when they really don't? And putting multiple statements on a single line could also mislead you to believe they belong to the same scope.

Comment: it is unclear why you use modulo for `i%n`, when `0 <= i < n` then `i % n == i`

Comment: Sie note: your code looks chaotic, and the lack of spaces isn't very helpful if you get what I'm saying...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Because of the `i+1` I would guess.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I think you're on to something.`else
            xa = x[(i + 1) % n];` and the rest after should be in the same block.

Comment: @goodvibration yeah realized that, still I woulndt sprinkle the modulo all over the place but rather use a `next_i = (i == n-1) ? 0 : i;` not the nicest line but still better then having it all over the place

Comment: @vladut Look at the lines after  `else xa = x[(i + 1) % n];` - they will be executed even if the `if` above evauates the expression as `true`.

Comment: tbh I think the real problem with your code is that it is hardly readable. Single letter variable names and not using functions to structure the code are some of the ingredients.

Comment: There are at least two assignments which take place inside `if` statements here. One of them is `if(y[i % n] = y[(i + 1) % n])` and the other one is `if (... && (ym = y[i % n])`. That's a really bad practice, unless we're dealing with a very short and easy to understand piece of code.

Comment: So i changed all the i%n whith i, and added a brace from else to the end of for.

Comment: Not enough. You use uninitialized variables in `if(d1(xm, ym, xa, ya, xb, yb) ... ` if the first `if` is `true`.

Comment: If `if(y[i % n] == y[(i + 1) % n])` is true, what values do you expect that `xm, ym, xa, ya, xb, yb` will have when you call `d1`? They are not initialized to `0` when you start your program.

Comment: *It works for the first element but it doesn't work for the rest* -- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  You wrote the program, thus learning how to debug your own programs is part and parcel in learning how to write programs.  -- *So i changed all the i%n whith i, and added a brace from else to the end of for.* -- You should be determining for yourself if the advice we give you is good or nonsense -- you shouldn't be blindly hoping whatever we say for you to try works.  Understand what **your** program is doing (wrong).

Comment: You've now changed the program so `d1(xm,ym,xa,ya,xb,yb)` is only checked in the last case. Have you been programming python? The indentation in C++ does not matter for anyone else than the readers of the code. Your compiler does not care. Read the code now when I've indented it again.

Comment: "_if the point doesn't cross a border,it just walks on it then we don't consider it as a cross._" - doesn't the point `15,15` fit in that category? It crosses `0` times - and since you have `if(c != 2) cout << "M interior\n";` - it will be reported as interior.

Comment: Did you mean `if(c % 2) cout << "M interior\n";`?

Comment: Yeah ,changed it to 'if(c % 2) cout << "M interior\n";' it was supposed to be odd or even.

Comment: Why do you destroy the formatting of the code with every edit? It's close to impossible for someone to read it - and I doubt you can either because as it is indented right now, I think you expect things to happen that will not happen. You have your old bug back I noticed after formatting it again.

Comment: I’m sorry, I was under the impression i am supposed to edit the code from the question, when it comes to the the code the opening curly brackets meant that the ifs after `if(y[i]<y[(i+1)%n])` were not executed.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Why do you keep your own code indented like you do? Many editors will indent it properly for you. You could have just copied the code after I had indented and you'd have something much easier to read - and edit.
The part after `else
            xa = x[(i + 1) % n];` is executed even if `if(y[i] < y[(i + 1) % n])` evauates to true again (bug). You use uninitialized values again (bug).